# handling html nested list element using perl XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Im processing the html list using perl XML::Twig.

The list element have the another nested list element like

```
<list list-type="bullet">
  <list-item>
    <p>Linea</p>
    <list list-type="bullet">
      <list-item>
        <p>Uno</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>vitara</p>
      </list-item>
     </list>
   </list-item>
   <list-item>
    <p>Panda</p>
   </list-item>
</list>
```

The output should be

```
<p>* Linea</p>
<p>** Uno</p>
<p>** vitara</p>
<p>* Panda</p>
```

Can anyone help me here to get this output using XML::Twig

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can get the number of enclosing lists by using `ancestors( 'list')` in scalar context (which returns the number of elements of the list). Use this value to generate the prefix with the proper number of '*':

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { 
  'list-item/p' => sub { my $level= $_->ancestors( 'list');
                         $_->prefix( '*' x $level . ' ');
                         $_->print;
                         print "\n";
                       }
  }
)
         ->parse( \*DATA);
__DATA__
<list list-type="bullet">
  <list-item>
    <p>Linea</p>
    <list list-type="bullet">
      <list-item>
        <p>Uno</p>
      </list-item>
      <list-item>
        <p>vitara</p>
      </list-item>
     </list>
   </list-item>
   <list-item>
    <p>Panda</p>
   </list-item>
</list>
```

Comment: Thanks Mirod, its working as expected. Can you help me how to skip the second <p> element inside each <list-item>.

Comment: if you want to skip the 2cd p, but output all the others, add `return if $_->prev_siblings('p') == 1;` at the beginning of the handler (return if the current p has a single previous sibling). If you only want to output the first `p`, add `return if $_->prev_sibling('p');` (return if the current p has a previous sibling)